# How to smooth NDVI raster (Sentinel 2-A image) in ArcGis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ndvi, smoothing, sentinel-2, image-analysis

My question is regarding the final  display of a NDVI raster.

I currently work with ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.2.

When I work with Landsat images (the image is loaded as composition through the MTL file, after i calculate apparent reflectance function in ArcGis,  and finally NDVI through "image Analisys" module). Using "streched simbology " the image is very visual and useful in a smoothly way, for example:
[image: Landsat Image]

However, with the Sentinel 2-A images downloaded from ESA recently, I've still not managed the way to do so visual. In this case I downloaded through the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin (fromgistors) plugin using "DOS 1 atmospheric correction." In this case, I could not (do not know if there form) to load the image as a composition (accompanies an XML archive I guess it's for that, but I have not found a way), so charge the bands individually and calculate the NDVI (even checking the box scientific output in "Image analisys module"). I also use "Streched simbology" to represent the image, but the quality is very low, it appears pixelated. Example:
[image: ESA 2A image]

I don't know the cause why this happens, and that is my question: do you know any way to smooth or blur the final raster (GRID)  in ArcMap?

Answer (score 5):

For visualisation purpose, you can select a resampling method from the display properties. right click on layer > properties, then  display tab / **resampling during display using** : cubic convolution (cubic convolution yields the smoothest display, bilinear interpolation also works).

[image]

here is an example with a S2 image, with cubic convolution (top) and without (bottom). Note that your "quality" impression is the real pixel size (10 m), which would be 30 m if you display the Landsat-8 image at its true resolution (i.e. using nearest neighbour resampling)

[image: smoothed image (cubic convolution)]

[image]

Comment: Thank you.
I think that's the solution, the problem is that I haven't among the functions of arcgis the "Resampling" function, so I think that is why I do not work for me.

Comment: this is located in the properties of your layer (right click on layer in the table of content). You don't need any extension; See my print screen.